# SSH automatically disconnects after file transfer

Tags: ssh, sftp, ftp

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 on a machine in my house that I use for web development. I connect to it using Filezilla SFTP to transfer files from my office. When I connect and only browse, the connection will remain active for extended periods of time (desired result). However, when I transfer a file, after the queue is complete, I get disconnected after ~10 seconds. What could be causing this?

I've tried `TCPKeepAlive yes / no`, ClientAliveInterval, neither seem to help.

Comment: Any relevant information in server logs?

Comment: I'd bet £1 it's related to the firewall you're traversing at work (assuming when you say 'your office' there's a corporate firewall protecting you from the evils of the internet) - but I don't know how you could prove / solve the issue if that's it.  Does it happen from non-office locations in the same way?

Comment: what about scp? if you scp a file does the same thing happen? if not, then filezilla is sending something to close the connection after the transfer.

Comment: Can you define "transfer a file"?

Comment: scp doesn't keep connection open anyway.